# C++, function with changing amount of inputs (idk how to describe)

Tags: c++, c++11

The funcion HIGHEST is all good and accepts variable number of arguments. The problem is how do I do variable amount of input? (idk what terms should be use to describe it, but examples should clear things up...)

/*cout << highest(n, A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3]) <<endl;
this is what I would like to achieve,
but with a change - the number of array changes with
the input file and n defines how many of these will be.
ex.: if n = 7 it needs to be (n, A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3], A[4], A[5], A[6])
*/

Duom.txt file if needed (i am now only working with 1st number 4 under it others will follow same/similar thing as 1st row they are not important now)

4

2008 5 2000.00 400.25

2010 5 4000.00 320.25

2009 9 3385.00 254.45

2008 6 1900.00 612.59

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;
//Variable number of arguments in C++
int highest (int num,...) {
   va_list valist;
   int max = 0;
   int a;
   va_start(valist, num);
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        a = va_arg(valist, int);
        if(max < a) max = a;
        else ;
   }
   va_end(valist);
   return max;
}




int main () {
int n, A[25], B[25];
double C[25], D[25];

ifstream fd ("Duom.txt");
ofstream fr ("Rez.txt");
fd >> n;
cout << n <<endl;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fd >> A[i] >> B[i] >> C[i] >> D[i];
}
cout << highest(n, ) <<endl;
/*cout << highest(n, A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3]) <<endl;  
this is what I would like to achieve, 
but with a change - the number of array changes with 
the input file and n defines how many of these will be. 
ex.: if n = 7 it needs to be (n, A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3], A[4], A[5], A[6])
*/


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array, instead of a `vector`. Also, why do you want to pass the contents of the array as multiple arguments, instead of passing the array itself?

Comment: I am new to codding/c++ in general, i am just learning and I just  learned a way to make a funcion with Variable number of arguments and was wondering if there is a way to make similar stuff to the input for the funcion as well (idk how that part of code is called i am new...)

Comment: also you mentioned vectors - should i be looking into vectors not arrays? if so could you link me some where to look at the syntax i am looking for.

Comment: See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for how a function can accept arbitrary number of arguments in C++. However, unpacking an array into multiple arguments is not a good idea.

Comment: An explanation of `vector`s should be available in whatever learning resources you're using.

Comment: ok thanks, i ll look into that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there a specific reason you want the function Highest to get all array integers separately? Also - why did you choose to use an array instead of a vector?

Assuming that you want to use an array, I'd suggest to change the function's arguments as follows:

```
int highest (int num,int *arr);
```

where arr is the name of your array and in fact a pointer to the first integer of the array.
Then, inside the function, you can just access the array using subscript notation or dereferencing:

```
first_array_int=*(arr); //dereferencing example
second_array_int=*(arr+1); //dereferencing example
```

or

```
first_array_int=arr[0]; //subscript example
second_array_int=arr[1]; //subscript example
```

note that by doing that you can change the passed array within the function.

Again, I'd suggest to use a vector instead, then define the function:

```
int highest (int num,vector <int> *A);
```

if you want to pass a pointer, or:

```
int highest (int num,vector <int> A);
```

if you want to pass by value. Ofcourse, don't forget to include the vector library with

```
#include <vector>
```

I hope I understood your question well and that this is helpful.

Goodluck!

Guy

Comment: I choose array instead of a vector because I only know an array i never heard of vector (i am really new to c++), and yes, am pretty sure you understood my question (i didnt try it yet but i am pretty certain the first way will work), and what I understood from you and the other guy - I should be looking into vectors for these kinds of programing problems.

Comment: You can use arrays, it would work. It's just harder. C++ has the benefit of object oriented programming, which also includes standard objects such as vectors. Good luck!